# Get next element of Back-Stack in Android

Tags: android

I want to change the behaviour of my back button.
I already found out that I have to override the onBackPressed()-Method.
I'd like to check then, if a function like `getActivity().popBackStackItem()` returns activity (or whatever) X or something different from the BackStack of the system. In case of result is activity X, I want to change the behaviour (to close the app for example), otherwise the super-method shall be called and the activity of the BackStack shall be executed.

Main question is: Does a function like `popBackStackItem()` exists? Didn't found something like this until yet.

I already had a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html), but I don't want to create a completely new stack, I think checking the content in the system-wide BackStack should be enough here.

Comment: You could put the logic in the onActivityResult of Activity X. That means you start following activities with startActivityForResult and when you come back you check where you come from and finish the Activity also for example.

Comment: Check my demo https://github.com/rathodchintan/Fragment-Back-Stack

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways:

1 - in onbackpress call new activity - this is a very difficult logic

2 - convert your logic to fragment and call fragment by tag